# How to run executable file on Windows 7, which has been created as an relaese by Qt Creator version 5.0.2?

Tags: c++, qt, dll

The main issue of the problem is that application is crashing with error **"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way"**
After including all of the files as:
D3DCompiler_43.dll, icuuc49.dll, icuin49.dll, libEGL.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll, libGLESv2.dll, Qt5GUI.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll,
and also creating directory named platforms containing qwindows.dll and qminimal.dll

Comment: When you run it from QtCreator, does it run without any issues?

Comment: The problem was solved by including directory "platforms" containing qwindows.dll file to "release" directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to verify that you have copied all the needed Dlls.

Comment: I've tried dependency and almost everything from https://forum.qt.io/topic/24553/this-application-has-requested-the-runtime-to-terminate-it-in-an-unusual-way/8 and it finished with no successful results. Exe file is working on Win OS with Qt creator package on which the exe file was build, but the main goal is to make the application work on system without Qt Creator.